# What is the meaning of .xxxxxxx in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wonder what is the meaning of `.xxxxxx` (e.g. `.50109912`) in Python Tkinter. I was trying to check what is returned by `Widget_name(container, **configuration options).pack()`
Of course it will return `None` But when I check what is returned by the widget before packing, it gives something as this `.50109912`. This is how I got it in IDLE Python3.3.

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> mybutton = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=root.destroy)
>>> print(mybutton)
.50109912
```

Comment: That's the string representation of your button. Widget classes override their `__str__` methods to return a decimal-looking string instead of the usual `<Tkinter.Button instance at ...>` that you usually see when you print an object. But I'm guessing what you're _really_ asking is "what do these numbers represent?". I have no idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number `50109912` is the unique Python object id of the button widget:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> mybutton = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=root.destroy)
>>> print(mybutton)
.38321104
>>> id(mybutton)
38321104
>>>
```

Moreover, the string `.50109912` is the button widget's window path name.  Window path names are used internally by the TCL interpreter to keep track of widgets as well as what their parents are.  In other words, they are paths for the interpreter to follow in order to reach particular widgets.

You'll notice too that `50109912` is the same number returned by the [`winfo_name`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_name-method) method:

```
>>> mybutton.winfo_name()
'38321104'
>>>
```

Note however that `winfo_name` only returns the last portion of a widget's window path name (its object id).  To get the full path, you need to call `widget.__str__()` by doing either `str(widget)` or `print(widget)`.

---

The documentation for calling `widget.__str__()` can found through [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help):

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> help(tkinter.Button.__str__)
Help on function __str__ in module tkinter:

__str__(self)
    Return the window path name of this widget.

>>>
```

In addition, you may be interested in the [Basic Widget Methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) page over on Effbot (specifically, the section which talks about the `.winfo_*` methods).  It contains information about how to get specific parts of a widget's window path name.

---

Also, if you want the Python representation of the object, you can use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> mybutton = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=root.destroy)
>>> print(repr(mybutton))
<tkinter.Button object at 0x0248BBD0>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you iCodeZ for this comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
subframe = tk.Frame(frame)
label = tk.Label(subframe)

for widget in (root, button, frame, subframe, label):
    print('{:<8} id {:<20} str {!s:30} '.format(type(widget).__name__, id(widget), widget))
```

yields

```
Tk       id 140490446651632      str .                              
Button   id 140490446651744      str .140490446651744               
Frame    id 140490446651688      str .140490446651688               
Frame    id 140490417530808      str .140490446651688.140490417530808 
Label    id 140490417531368      str .140490446651688.140490417530808.140490417531368
```

As you can see, the `str` of the widget is a `.` for the root widget, and is a dot-separated sequence of `id` numbers for child widgets. The sequence of id numbers shows the lineage of the widget.

Comment: Thank you, unutbu, for this consise, yet professional answer. By virtue of your answer, I also came to konw the uses of {:<x} notation. I will use it quite often from now onward. One more remark about you is that 253k reputation is quite impressive. Wow!!